# ddrescue: 0% rescued on audio CD with 1 track that skips

Tags: data-recovery, iso, ddrescue, safecopy

I'm trying to get some lightly scratched albums (audio CDs) onto my computer via `ddrescue`. I ran the program on one disc with one track that has skipping problems, and it rescued 0%. The .iso was unmountable.

I tried `safecopy` (ran for 3 days) and also ended up with an unmountable iso.

I've tried a couple of different command line options, to no avail. Sudo and non-sudo.

```
ddrescue -f -n /dev/sr0 /path/to/iso.iso
ddrescue -n -b 2048 
ddrescue -f -d -R --force
```

I've tried `ddrescue` on another CD without any playback issues and still got 0% recovered.

What gives?

Comment: Wrong tool. Use `icedax` or `cdda2wav`

Comment: there's also `cdparanoia` which has scratch detection and correction features

Answer (score 1):

`ddrescue` can’t read audio tracks, you’ll need to use another tool to read audio CDs:

- [`cdrdao`](http://cdrdao.sourceforge.net/) (which will allow you to keep inter-track information, useful *e.g.* for gapless audio CDs)
- [CDDA Paranoia](https://www.xiph.org/paranoia/)
- [`morituri`](https://github.com/thomasvs/morituri), which supports AccurateRip checks but is getting harder to run on current distributions

Most desktop environments also include GUI tools which can rip audio CDs, *e.g.* [Sound Juicer](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/SoundJuicer), and there also are DE-agnostic GUI rippers such as [Asunder](http://www.littlesvr.ca/asunder/).